# timezone.js not working in zend framework 2

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, timezone

I am trying timezone conversion in javascript but I keep getting this in my console while using timezone.js :

**warning** : Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

**error**: GET http://exodo/tz/asia 404 (Not Found)

**error** : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

```
timezoneJS.timezone.zoneFileBasePath = 'tz';
timezoneJS.timezone.defaultZoneFile = ['asia', 'backward', 'northamerica', 'southamerica'];
timezoneJS.timezone.init({ async: false });
var dt = new window.timezoneJS.Date(new Date());
console.debug(dt.toString());
dt.setTimezone('America/Los_Angeles');
alert(dt);
```

prompt answers will be much appreciated

Thank you

Comment: does your Filebase path is correct? check your network.. the XMLHttpRequest  is failing..

Comment: Yes the FileBasePath is correct, I was missing some Olson files which timezone uses to operate. Thanks for the quick reply though

Comment: I am still getting the XMLHttpRequest warning but the timezone conversion is working great.

Comment: I already had async:false  in the code  snipet and It was already giving the warning.

Comment: Just tried it but got this error  Uncaught Error: Timezone 'Europe/Rome' is either incorrect, or not loaded in the timezone registry.

Comment: That's because your next lines are getting executed before data is loaded. So use callback : successFunction .. And put your last 4 lines inside this var successFunction = function(){ var dt = new window.timezoneJS.Date(new Date()); console.debug(dt.toString()); dt.setTimezone('America/Los_Angeles'); alert(dt)}

Comment: Ignore any typos.. Replying from mobile

Comment: I've struggled update answer :D from mobile

Comment: So you mean like this timezoneJS.timezone.init({ async: false },successFunction )?  I just tried but still got the same warning.

Comment: No no! Check my updated answer.. Remove async property at all

Comment: Oh ok sorry, trying now

Comment: nothing in the console(that's good) but no alert to output the result

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you see that  **GET** `http://exodo/tz/asia 404 (Not Found)` is failing.

You'll need the Olson time zone files -- timezoneJS.Date uses the raw Olson data to calculate timezone offsets. The Olson region files are simple, structured text data, which download quickly and parse easily. (They also compress to a very small size.)You can download from [here](http://www.iana.org/time-zones)

Put your directory of Olson files somewhere under your Web server root, and point timezoneJS.timezone.zoneFileBasePath to it. Then call the init function. Your code will look something like this:

```
timezoneJS.timezone.zoneFileBasePath = '/tz';
```

For more details read  [How to setup?](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js/blob/master/README.md)

```
        timezoneJS.timezone.zoneFileBasePath = '/tz';
 timezoneJS.timezone.defaultZoneFile = ['asia', 'backward', 'northamerica', 'southamerica'];
    var successFn = function (){ 
var dt = new window.timezoneJS.Date(new Date());
 console.debug(dt.toString());
 dt.setTimezone('America/Los_Angeles'); 
alert(dt);
}; 
timezoneJS.timezone.init({ callback: successFn });
```

Comment: I was not sure what /tz was supposed to holds. Just added those files and it is working great. Thank you